# Django URL dispatcher not matching named group

Tags: python, regex, django

I'm trying to make a DJango site, but the group matching in the URL dispatcher is giving me "p" no matter what I enter into the URL. Here's the pertinent parts of my code:

From user's urls.py (it does get included in the main urls.py)

```
url(r'^lookup?(?P<match_str>\w+)/$', views.lookup, name='user_lookup')
```

From views.py

```
def lookup(request, match_str):
    users = User.objects.filter(name__contains=match_str)
    json = serializers.serialize("json", users)
    return json
```

And a couple log entries:

```
[01/Jul/2014 22:43:17] "GET /user/lookup/?z HTTP/1.1" 500 11363
[01/Jul/2014 22:43:18] "GET /user/lookup/?za HTTP/1.1" 500 11363
```

On closer inspection, it looks like my AJAX is actually sending two calls, and the second call is actually what's being matched. The logs for the second calls of the above log lines are:

```
[01/Jul/2014 22:43:17] "GET /merchant/lookup?z HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[01/Jul/2014 22:43:18] "GET /merchant/lookup?za HTTP/1.1" 301 0
```

I put a "debug" line in the view to `print match_str` and no matter I put it, I get 'p'. What is going on here?

---

Per karthikr's request, here's the result of `print request.GET, match_str`

```
<QueryDict: {u'za': [u'']}> p
```

Comment: Probably not a good idea to do this.`lookup/(?P<match_str>\w+)/` and have the URL sent as `/user/lookup/za/` would be cleaner. `?` are for GET paramters, which you access by doing `request.GET.get('blah')`

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't thinking so either, but that's how I get the URL from an AJAX call...maybe that's what I need to look into changing instead...

Comment: @karthikr I'm inexperienced with AJAX, so I didn't realize how simple it would be to change the URL. I changed it now, and it's getting the correct value for `match_str`. However, I'm still hoping someone will be able to answer why it was only returning 'p' previously, just for knowledge's sake.

Comment: Just do `print request.GET, match_str` -> You will see why. If not, just edit the question with the results, and notify me.

Comment: @karthikr Added to the the question. It didn't really help me understand...is that what you were expecting it to display?

Answer (score 0):

Your regex doesn't match the URL from the log. The GET goes to `/user/lookup`, and the string `user` is not contained in Django's `url` Changing your regex to `^lookup/\?(?P<match_str>\w+)$`, the request `lookup/?someuser` creates a named group `match_str` with the value `someuser`.

I recommend using one of the many online regex testers to play with the URL regex.

Comment: The weird thing is that it _is_ matching the regex. On closer inspection, it looks like my AJAX is sending two calls, the second looks like `[01/Jul/2014 22:54:04] "GET /merchant/lookup?za HTTP/1.1" 301 0` I'll update the question too.